# Making a movie from an interpolating function

Tags: dynamic, interpolation

Say I use some Mathematica procedures to find an interpolating function of two variables: $u(x,t)$. Is it possible to make a movie of this interpolating function, i.e. plot it on a certain line $x \in [0,L]$, while the time $t$ increases continously?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You can animate it and export the animation to movie

Comment: @Nasser I tried something like Animate[Plot[u[t, x], {x, 0, L}], {t, 0, tmax}], but it doesn't seem to work. Additionally, could you tell me how to export an animation to a movie?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update** for comment to make the movie without the slider showing:

[image]

To make the above, used Manipulate, since little more flexible. Used `Invisible` Control. Here is the code.

```
p = Manipulate[
  Plot[u[x, t], {x, -4 Pi, 4 Pi}, Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> {{"u(x)", None}, {"x", 
      Row[{"time", Spacer[2], AccountingForm[t, {2, 1}, 
     NumberPadding -> {"0", "0"}] , Spacer[2], "sec"}]}}, ImageMargins -> 10],
  Invisible[Control[{{t, 0, "time"}, 0, 20, .1, ImageSize -> 0}]],
  AutoRemove -> {1},
  Initialization :>
   (
    c = 1;
    u[x_, t_] := Sin[x - c t]
    )
  ]
```

and in new cell

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
Export["foo.avi", p]
```

### Original answer

Make an animation, for example, wave moving

```
c = 1;
u[x_, t_] := Sin[x - c t]
p = Animate[Plot[u[x, t], {x, -4 Pi, 4 Pi}], {t, 0, 20}];
```

Then export it

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
Export["foo.mov", p]
```

[image]

**added for comment:**

Animate needs a parameter to use for the slider, as follows

```
sol = NDSolve[{
    D[u[t, x], t] == D[u[t, x], {x, 2}],
    u[0, x] == 0, u[t, 0] == Sin[t], u[t, 5] == 0},
   u, {t, 0, 20}, {x, 0, 5}];
Animate[Plot3D[Evaluate[u[t, x] /. sol], {t, 0, i}, {x, 0, 5}, 
  PlotRange -> All, ImagePadding -> 20, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], {i, .1, 20, .1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Your example works like a charm. However, if I try something like NDSolve[{D[u[t, x], t] == D[u[t, x], x, x], u[0, x] == 0, u[t, 0] == Sin[t], u[t, 5] == 0}, u, {t, 0, 10}, {x, 0, 5}] and then do p = Animate[Plot[u[t, x], {x, 0, 5}], {t, 0, 10}]; I get a blank movie..

Comment: @Funzies you did  not do it correctly. added the example. Now just put `p=Animnate....` as before, and export it. Should work

Comment: Thanks a lot, you were very helpful!

Comment: @Nasser  How can the Animator bar be eliminated from the movie?  Thanks.

Comment: @bbgodfrey yes. I used Manipulate, which is little more flexible to make the move. Please see update